# Formula for the correlation between two different variables

Tags: random-variables, correlation

> Jon planted a plant. When the plant grew to $4\,cm$ tall he decided to start to measure how much the plant grew each week.
>
> Here are Jon's measurements:
>
> Week $0$: $\;\;4\,cm$
> Week $1$: $\;\;6\,cm$
> Week $2$: $10\,cm$
> Week $3$: $10\,cm$
> Week $4$: $13\,cm$
> Week $5$: $17\,cm$
> Week $6$: $17\,cm$
> Week $7$: $18\,cm$
> Week $8$: $21\,cm$
> Week $9$: $22\,cm$
>
> Write a formula to describe the correlation between the plant's height and the number of weeks.

So I'm really not understanding this assignment. There are several weeks where the plant doesn't grow. That means that I can't really say that $y = 2x + something$ because if that "something" for example was $4$, then yes it would be right on Week $0$ and Week $1$ ($2*0+4=4$ and $2*1+4 = 6$), but if we look at Week $2$ it's not right.

Can someone please explain to me how I should think when trying to solve these kind of assignments?

**Edit:** The same assignment also asks to calculate with the formula, how tall the plant will be at Week $14$.

Comment: The point of correlation is to get a formula that's in some sense "as good as possible" to model the data. The process of fitting a line with minimal errors is called [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression): if you haven't learned about this I don't see how you could complete the assignment.

Comment: @Joffan: The thing is, this assignment was used for fourteen year old students at a test, and I'm just wondering if the strategy of "as good as possible" will really work on future tests. But if I got this correct, the next time I see an assignment like this, my strategy would be to look on week 0 and 1 and get a formula from those weeks and just proceed to write it as the correct formula? I know this may be a weird question but it's just strange to me, that's all.

Comment: No, there's a process to follow to get a straight-line fit which has minimal errors (I linked the wikipedia article in my last comment). The first thing I would do, though, is graph the data and see if a straight line is appropriate.

Comment: @Joffan: Well, this won't give a straight line as several weeks give the same height, but you're telling me that by using a graph, you could search for the optimal formula? (Or am I misunderstanding something?) Edit: Just saw the link, but it seems too advanced for a 14 year old.

Comment: It's not simple, that's for sure. The article is quite theory-heavy which makes it more scary perhaps. But the idea is to fit a line through the centre of gravity of the points $(\bar{x},\bar{y})$ and set the slope for minimum errors. For a 14-year-old I would be satisfied with drawing a graph, manually drawing a good fit line and then calculating the formula from the graph.

Comment: Excel will fit this line on a graph and can also report the formula, incidentally. In this case giving $y = 2.0121x + 4.7455$.

Comment: @Joffan: That's nice. Anyway though, I made a graph and finally found out how to get the formula $y = 2x+4$ (where $y$ is equal to the height of the plant and $x$ is the weeks) by just simplifying it a little. Thank you for your help though, I'll remember about linear regression for later if I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a graph and simplified the line in order to get the formula that $y = 2x + 4$ where $y$ stands for the height of the plant and $x$ is the number of weeks. It's not that hard if you make the graph yourself and simply try to come up with the most optimal formula that you can achieve (remember, this assignment is ment for fourteen year olds, so you can't expect more than that).